# automatically assign g=rw privileges

Tags: linux, privileges

I have a simple script that change the privileges of some directory. This script is run by my iRODS application with irods linux user. For this I need to execute this script with sudo. I edite the sudores file `visudo -f /etc/sudoers` to allow use sudo with no password.

```
Defaults:irods    !requiretty
irods ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD:ALL
```

.

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo chmod -R u=$PRI_USER,g=$PRI_GROUP,o=$PRI_OTHERS $DIR
```

this is working. My problem is that I create directories with u=rw,g=r,o=r privileges and my script cannot change the privileges to u=rw,g=rw,o=rw. Only if my directory is created with u=rw,g=rw privileges I can change the privileges using my script. It is because my app execute with irods linux user and I created the directory with g=read-only.

```
$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr--r-- 2 ajongejan irods 4096 Mar  1 02:47 Overige-Joana-s1
```

How do I impose to the user create all files and directories with g=rw? I would like to have a trigger on the bashrc that all files that he create on his directory the privileges g=rw is assigned automatically.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run

```
umask 0002
```

for each user when they login.

That'll give the permissions u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx for each file or directory they create. They'll need the x to change into those directories.

Comment: but still does not work if I copy form another user to the home directory that I set umask 0002. It only applies if I create the directory.